# BASH Script not adding variables in the Function

Tags: linux, bash, lubuntu

My script with the addition function will not execute the add operator (+) with two variables that I assign numeric values based on read. The other functions will work fine using the other operators.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                              

function addition {                                      
   FNUM1=$1                                              
   FNUM2=$2                                              
   RESULT=$((FNUM1+FNUM2))                               
   echo "RESULT: $RESULT"                                          
}                                                        

function subtraction {                                    
   FNUM1=$1                                              
   FNUM2=$2                                              
   RESULT=$((FNUM1-FNUM2))                               
   echo "RESULT: $RESULT"                                          
}                                                        

function multiplication {                                       
   FNUM1=$1                                              
   FNUM2=$2                                              
   RESULT=$((FNUM1*FNUM2))                               
   echo "RESULT: $RESULT"                                          
}                                                        

function division {                                      
   FNUM1=$1                                              
   FNUM2=$2                                              
   RESULT=$((FNUM1/FNUM2))                               
   echo "RESULT: $RESULT"                                          
}                                                        

clear
echo "Please select a calculation to make!"              
echo "Choose how to you want to calculate two numbers"

COUNTER=0                                                

while [ $COUNTER -eq 0 ]                                 
do                                                       
   echo ""                                               
   echo "1 - addition"                                   
   echo "2 - subtraction"                                
   echo "3 - multiplication"                             
   echo "4 - division"                                   
   echo "5 - QUIT"                                       

   read CHOICE                                           

   case $CHOICE in                                       
      1)                                                 
         echo "YOU CHOSE ADDITION!"                      
         echo "Enter first number: "                     
         read NUM1                                       
         echo "Added by: "                               
         read NUM2                                       
         addition $NUM1 $NUM                             
         ;;                                              
      2)
         echo "YOU CHOSE SUBTRACTION!"                   
         echo "Enter first number: "                     
         read NUM1                                       
         echo "Subtracted by: "                          
         read NUM2                                       
         subtraction $NUM1 $NUM2                         
         ;;                                              
      3)                                                 
         echo "YOU CHOSE MULTIPLICATION!"                
         echo "Enter first number: "                     
         read NUM1                                       
         echo "Multiplied by: "                          
         read NUM2                                       
         multiplication $NUM1 $NUM2                      
         ;;                                              
      4)                                                 
         echo "YOU CHOSE DIVISION!"                      
         echo "Enter first number: "                     
         read NUM1                                       
         echo "Divided by: "                             
         read NUM2                                       
         division $NUM1 $NUM2                            
         ;;                                              
      5)                                                 
         COUNTER=$(( $COUNTER + 1 ))                     
         ;;                                              
      *)                                                 
         echo "You must enter a number from 1 through 5!"
   esac                                                  
done
```

Output:

```
Please select a calculation to make!

Choose how to you want to calculate two numbers
1 - addition
2 - subtraction
3 - multiplication
4 - division
5 - QUIT
1
YOU CHOSE ADDITION!
Enter first number:
24
Added by:
5
RESULT: 24
```

I want the addition function to add the values that are read into the FNUM1 and FNUM2 variables.

Comment: `addition $NUM1 $NUM`  -- you have a typo there, the `2` of `NUM2` is missing. `set -u` might be useful to spot issues like that, it causes the shell to throw an error if it encounters an unset variable.

Comment: I pasted your code to https://www.shellcheck.net and get message: `addition $NUM1 $NUM - Possible misspelling: NUM may not be assigned, but NUM1 is.` Very handy service, use it.

Answer (score 1):

As ilkkachu commented, you have a simple typo in your addition code:

```
     echo "Added by: "                               
     read NUM2                                       
     addition $NUM1 $NUM
```

should be:

```
     echo "Added by: "                               
     read NUM2                                       
     addition $NUM1 $NUM2
```

Ditto the commented recommendations for ShellCheck and [`set -u`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin) for these kinds of errors. `set -u` would have given you an error when executing the script.

> Treat unset variables and parameters other than the special parameters ‘@’ or ‘*’ as an error when performing parameter expansion. An error message will be written to the standard error, and a non-interactive shell will exit.